# Updating $geometry in QGIS processing modeler?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I'm creating a `Qgis` model with Processing modeler. I can't find how to update the `$geometry` field from a `WKT field`. If I complete the step by step process, I used the field calculator with the formula `geom_from_wkt("WKT_path")`, but it doesn't work within the processing modeler.

Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update feature geometry from the Field Calculator. Instead use the **Geometry by expression** tool (find it in the Processing Toolbox).

> "This algorithm updates existing geometries (or creates new geometries) for input features by use of a QGIS expression. This allows complex geometry modifications which can utilize all the flexibility of the QGIS expression engine to manipulate and create geometries for output features." - *excerpt from the tool description in QGIS*

Your expression, `geom_from_wkt("WKT_path")`, should work in this tool, as long as the layer has a field called "WKT_path" with the new geometries in WKT format.